# Android: startActivity in onResume() method has delay

Tags: java, android, onresume

I am creating a simple button application for Android. The application controls a very expensive machine so I have to make sure that user cannot accidentally click on any button. So I created a "lock" screen as an activity and start it whenever the application becomes active (when onResume() method is called). But when I am inside the app and just lock the phone and then unlock it I can see the activity for about half a second before the "lock" screen jumps in.

I was trying to start it when onPause() is called, but when the back button is pressed, it will navigate to "lock" screen instead of going out of the app.

I was wondering if I can put the activity to the front but activate it when onResume() method is called.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can use lock view with button view. As per your need, you can show/hide the lock view.

Comment: You might just want to have a ON/OFF overlay view instead, to show or hide (`Visibility.VISIBLE` or `Visibility.GONE` depending of if you want the app to be locked or not

Comment: I understand. So I make my activity invisible and I would experience only a little delay between unlocking mobile phone and opening my "lock" screen. My problem was not functional. I was not able to click any button, but the customer does not like it :-). I will try it. Thank you.